# Why is my error catching unreachable?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I've create my own parsing method which takes case sensitivity and capture groups as parameters. I'd like to be able to handle users putting in a capture group that doesn't exist, just a simple console print informing me that's what's happened. Why can this catch statement not be reached?

```
        do
        {
            regex.enumerateMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all)
            {
                    (result: NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in let theResult = nsString.substringWithRange(result!.rangeAtIndex(captureGroup))
                    resultsArray.append(theResult)
            }
            return resultsArray
        }
            //Todo: Make this reachable
        catch
        {
            print("The chosen capture group does not exist.")
            return(["Error"])
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only errors of methods which `throw` can be caught in a `do - catch` block

`enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:` does not `throw`

[Swift Language Guide: Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Comment: Hi Vadian, thanks. What should I be doing to prepare for someone putting a 3 in my capture group parameter when there are only two capture groups within the regex?

Comment: Compare the number of matches / groups

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing 'try' statement? Can you check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html for reference?